# How do I get rid of an unneeded text thats from a cout in a loop? C++ (Picture)

Tags: c++

Screenshot:

[image]

Where it shows "The sum of 2 + 1 + 3 + is 6", I want to get rid of that last "+" sign after 3, as it obviously doesn't look good to show. Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of it?

Thank you in advance!

```
    cout << "The sum of ";

    for (i = 1; i <= InputLimit; i++) // This loop shows all user entered 'elements' of the array

        cout << numbers[i] << " + ";

    cout << " is " << sum << ". ";
```

Comment: Please post the code rather than a screenshot of it.

Comment: As you are into screenshots - use Photoshop

Comment: Added the code, sorry! First time on StackOverflow!

Comment: Do you know arrays start at zero?

Comment: I know arrays start at zero, but if I made i=0, it would say "Please enter in number 0: for the first thing. Hard to explain but its fine. :)

Comment: Have you heard of the if statement

Comment: There's a lot of ways to solve this -- but all of them involve changing how you handle output the last time through your loop/control structure.

Comment: Use `std::copy` with an [infix ostream iterator](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489).

Comment: @Jordan _'Hard to explain but its fine. :) '_ I seriously doubt this :-/ ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I fixed it to the way it should be. :)

Comment: @Jordan Having a non zero based array index somewhere is a **big indicator** you did some nonsense elsewhere. _'"Please enter in number 0: for the first thing' ..._ If you just want to prompt a _human readable_ index add one (`+ 1`) and output this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yup that's exactly what I did! Thank you.

Comment: @JohnPaulAshenfelter Or the first time.  Array indexes normally start at zero, and something like `if ( i != 0 ) std::cout << '+'` is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just put a conditional:

```
for (i = 0; i <= InputLimit; i++){ // This is just the loop to show the numbers with '+' or no.
        if (i != InputLimit){
                cout << numbers[i] << " + ";
        }
        else {
                cout << numbers[i];
        }
}
```

I hope it works for you XD

Comment: You shouldn't reproduce obvious errors from the OP's code in your answers. Fix them, if necessary explain what and why you've fixed it.

Comment: I know, but just replacing this part of the code will works for him...
It wasn't a big problem, he needed just to put a conditional to control when the plus sinal will appears or not.
 -> And as you have already seen, it worked, so, why did you give me -1?
 @Jordan -> If you need something else, just tell XD